# Como saber se a frase está na lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quero que em alguns casos apareça a mensagem "Uhul! Seu amigo secreto vai adorar", mas a variável presente sempre dá como resposta "Tente Novamente", exemplo: na variável 'pessoa_presentes' eu digito 'pedro camisa teclado cadeira', na variável presente quando eu digitasse 'pedro camisa' era para dizer que eu acertei, mas diz "Tente Novamente", como corrigir esse erro no meu código.

**Código:**

```
participantes = int(input('Número de participantes: '))
lista_pessoas = []
for p in range(participantes):
    pessoa_presentes = input('Digite seu nome e os 3 presentes desejados: ')
    lista_pessoas.append(pessoa_presentes)
print(lista_pessoas)
presente = ''
while presente != 'FIM':
    presente = input('Qual presente você deseja dar: ')
    if presente != 'FIM':
        if presente in lista_pessoas:
            print('Uhul! Seu amigo secreto vai adorar')
        else:
            print('Tente Novamente!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite Pedro.

O que vc esta fazendo não vai dar certo pois vc não esta verificando a variavel `presente` com outra string mas sim com a lista de pessoas gerada `lista_pessoas` para isso vc precisara iterar cada registro nessa lista. Outro impeditivo é que o operador `in` só vai funcionar caso as palavras estejam na mesma sequencia caso sua busca na string fosse  "pedro teclado" não iria funcionar, para isso sugiro que use o metodo split da seguinte forma.

```
while presente != 'FIM':
    presente = input('Qual presente você deseja dar: ').split(' ')
    if presente != 'FIM':
        for i in lista_pessoas:
            pessoa_presentes = i.split(' ')
            if pessoa_presentes[0] == presente[0] and presente[1] in  pessoa_presentes[1:]:
                print('Uhul! Seu amigo secreto vai adorar')
        else:
            print('Tente Novamente!')
```

Assim caso os inputs tenham um padrão vc utilizara o primeiro registro para comparar os nomes e os subsequntes para seriam para verificar se o presente foi sugerido

Comment: Nesse código a saída, quando acertamos, está saindo repetida e o laço nunca acaba.

Comment: Exato, vc pode colocar `presente = 'FIM'` ou simplesmente usar o comando `break` após o print